# Archive page for Custom Post Type taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a Custom Post Type called "gifts" and I am assigning a different Department to each type of gift (bags, t-shirts.) If you go to website.com/gifts/tshirts this page doesn't exist. **How do I show these subcategories? How do I make a page that shows them?** I thought they would show up in archive.php Note: If I go to website.com/gifts/ I can see ALL of the gifts.
Thanks

```
//Custom post types GIFTS//
function gifts_post_type(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Gifts',
            'singular_name' => 'Gift',            
            ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,     
        'description' => __( 'Gifts' ),    
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-money-alt',
        'show_in_rest' => true,//Adds link to change to block editor
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
        //'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'gifts'),
    );
    register_post_type('gifts',$args);
}
add_action('init','gifts_post_type');



//Custom post type GIFTS Taxonomy//
function gifts_taxonomy(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Departments',
            'singular_name' => 'Department',
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,    //True for categories, false for tags    
    );     
    register_taxonomy('gifts',array('gifts'),$args);
}
add_action('init','gifts_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have your post-type slug and taxonomy as the same slug so there's an easier distinction. You may also want to look into the `rewrite` parameter for both register_post_type and register_taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have no taxonomy rewrite. The taxonomy will try to use the taxonomy slug by default but will run into a conflict with your post type slug since they are both `gifts`. In my example below, I've changed your slugs to better reflect their origin, then I use the `rewrite` parameter and `has_archive` parameter to define what the permalinks should be.

```
// Custom post types GIFTS
function gifts_post_type(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => 'Gifts',
            'singular_name' => 'Gift',
        ),
        'description'   => __( 'Gifts' ),
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-money-alt',
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'    => array( 'tax_gifts' ), // Added our taxonomy as "supported" - not required.
        'has_archive'   => 'gifts', // Defines the post type archive as: '/gifts/'
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'gifts/item' ), // Defines the single post permalink as: '/gifts/item/$post-slug/'
    );

    // Changed 'gifts' to 'cpt_gifts' to denote that this is a Custom Post Type (CPT).
    register_post_type( 'cpt_gifts', $args );
}
add_action('init','gifts_post_type');

// Custom post type GIFTS Taxonomy
function gifts_taxonomy(){
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => 'Departments',
            'singular_name' => 'Department',
        ),
        'public'        => true,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,    // Needed so that the box show up in the Block Editor
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'gifts' ), // Defines our term archive as: '/gifts/$term-slug/'
    );

    // Changed 'gifts' to 'tax_gifts' to differentiate the post type from taxonomy.
    register_taxonomy( 'tax_gifts', array( 'cpt_gifts' ), $args );
}
add_action('init','gifts_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Hi Howdy_McGee,
Thank you so much for your answer. After posting my question. I found a website explaining how to do what I needed: https://awhitepixel.com/blog/create-custom-post-types-taxonomies-wordpress/
Thank you so much for your help!